# How to fade out, fade in a div on window scroll?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout, scrolltop

My div fades out nicely after 100px scrolled, but will not fade back in after 300px scrolled.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#menuWrap').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1000);   
            } 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $('#menuWrap').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
            }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `stop()` or `stop(true,true)` befaore `animate(..)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#menuWrap').stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1000);   
            } 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $('#menuWrap').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
            }
     });
});
```